# Transactions created using web3.py are stuck in geth queue and not broadcasted to rinkeby

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py, go-ethereum

I am running a geth node synched to rinkeby network. I set up some automated services that filter solidity events and create transactions(web3.py) when certain events are received. This worked fine for a while, but at the moment all my new transactions are stuck in geth's queue. I can see them if I do txpool.content.pending['0x190Af0A202e7464340A140D6C59ee755b6D27829'], or eth.pendingTransactions. However, I cannot see my transactions at all on etherscan which makes me thing geth didn't broadcast to network.

I tried overwriting the first transaction stuck by making a new one with the same nonce. I tried clean reinstalling geth. I tried waiting.

Comment: Any chance you skipped nonce 11155?

Comment: Possible, happened again on a fresh account. I fixed it by just manually submitting metamask transactions until all my pending ones got overwritten. The problem is, I am not sure what I did wrong that might have caused this so I don't really know how to avoid it happening again in the future. I am not manually setting the nonce.

Since then I've started manually setting the gasPrice and gas amount instead of letting web3.py determine it. Hasn't occurred again. Fingers crossed I guess.

Comment: gasPrice could easily be the issue. What price were the pending txs at?

Comment: Web3 defaulted it to like 1.00057 gwei. Seemed kind of low but all my other transactions seem to go through on 1 gwei when on rinkeby. Sorry if this is a noob question but is it best practices to let web3 determine your gasPrice and gas or are you supposed to try to calculate it yourself?
This is a fairly complicated transaction, with gas cost heavily dependent on state of the contract

Comment: You should be good to leave them both as the default, it doesn't seem like it's the problem. I'm not sure how to help debug without the pending transaction data, so it may just be a mystery till the next time it happens.